# Require override of specific methods of a non-abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, methods

Is it possible to have a class defined like

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void methodA(){} // Inherit
    public void methodB(){} // Inherit
    public void methodC(){} // Require override
}
```

and then have all classes which extend from MyClass to be required to override `methodC()` but just simply inherit `methodA()` and `methodB()`?

If it is possible, how does one do it? If it's not possible, can you propose an alternative solution to achieve a similar result?

EDIT:

I need a non-abstract class because I want to be able to instantiate this class too.

Comment: requiring an override is pretty much the definition of an abstract method or class.

Comment: I was thinking on all this; the IDE and the compilation promptly helps us to deal with it, in case we use abstraction; but.. I have a case where my code would become unnecessarily complex and hard to read... so I decided to create restrictions in runtime, when testing the application, all the restrictions pop up preventing it from running; is good enough to me :)

Comment: We can override a non abstract class too using runtime polymorphism. There is no need of base abstract class or final class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot require an override of a non-abstract method.

Maybe you can do something similar to the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method):

```
 public final void methodC() { methodC1(); someMoreLogic(); methodC2();}

 protected abstract void methodC1();

 protected abstract void methodC2();
```

Here methodC encapsulates a fixed algorithm that calls into pieces that have to be supplied by the subclasses.

Answer (score 15):

You would have to make your base class abstract.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public void methodA(){} // Inherit
    public void methodB(){} // Inherit
    public abstract void methodC(); // Require override
}
```

Comment: It is specified in the question that the class must be non-abstract.

Comment: Yes, and in the question, you stated that "if it is not possible can you propose an alternative solution"?

Comment: The question also does not give any background or motivation as to why it must be non-abstract.

Comment: OK, I see your point now. It's just that the answer wasn't provided clearly. I thought you were another one of those who don't read the question well. Sorry, I withdraw my downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you do exactly what you want. Alternatively, create MyBaseClass as an abstract class with `methodC()` abstract implementations for `methodA()` and methodB(). Derive MyClass from it, adding an implementation for `methodC()`. Any classes that you do not want to have inherit that implementation should directly subclass MyBaseClass rather than MyClass.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a method to be just inherited use `final` keyword. To force overriding make it `abstract`. However, only non-abstract child classes will have to override it.

Comment: OP edit: I need a non-abstract class because I want to be able to instantiate this class too.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to force override a method in Java with out abstract.

You can achive  with `abstract` class by making the `method as abstract` method.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it may be to use virtual keyword instead of abstract but it **doesnt require** to override, but you **can** do override. though so, you can  instantiate.

another way and more recommended is to create an interface where you can indicate what the class requirements. it is something like abstract, you indicate what to require, but keep in mind interface is not a class. it's more like pointer. for more for interface click: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Java does not have a virtual keyword, and methods are virtual by default. The `final` keyword makes methods non-virtual.

Answer (score 0):

So, java.lang.Thread is a concrete class that implements the Runnable interface. Therefore, it must be that Thread implements a public void run() method. Yet, when you extend Thread, like MyClass extends Thread { }, you are required to implement the run() method.

It stands to reason that there is a way to force overriding of a method without making the containing class abstract.